# Generate MD5 hash of file and compare to MD5 hash value from import txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, hash, md5

**Can someone help me about this? Beginner of python but need advanced script to do hash check
(My idea is to let the script compare every file hash value to the "malicious_hash.txt if match then print MATCH FOUND")**

```
import os
import hashlib


hashtype = "MD5"
malicious_hash = ("C:/Users/user/Downloads/malicious_hash.txt")



with open(malicious_hash, 'rb')as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  print(lines)

def cal_file_md5(filt_path):
    with open(filt_path, "rb") as f:
        file_hash = hashlib.md5()
        while chunk := f.read(1024 * 1024):
            file_hash.update(chunk)
    return file_hash.hexdigest()

def cal_folder_hash(folder):
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        print("Folder doesn't exist %s" % folder)
        return
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        path = os.path.join(folder, file)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            cal_folder_hash(path)
        else:
            print("File: %s" % path)
            md5 = cal_file_md5(path)
            print("MD5: %s\n" % md5)

cal_folder_hash("C:/Users/user/Downloads")
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? You seem to have got all the difficult part right, you only need to compare the md5 of each file as returned by `cal_file_md5()` with that of "malicious" and print filename and/or "match found" when they are equal, instead of just printing name and hash value

Comment: Yea, the whole script is take from somewhere else, I am still understand what the code say but I have no idea how to combine it and compare the given hash value from "malicious_hash.txt" to the file and if it is matched it will display "MATCH!"

If you are are programmer can you give me some advise or guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I have two issues with your question. First, it is unclear whether "malicious.hash.txt" is expected to hold a hash, or some contents that need to be hashed; and second, your treatment is rather unusual: you normally have a hash you received on a somehow secure channel, then receive a file and compute its hash to check if it is identical to the one you already have, so you're sure your file has not been tampered with.

That said let's see what your code does (since you said you are a beginner) and how it can be modified.

```
import os
import hashlib
```

Ok, we import the modules we'll need.

```
hashtype = "MD5"
malicious_hash = ("C:/Users/user/Downloads/malicious_hash.txt")
```

The first line is useless: you set a variable you never use, so let's delete it. And the parenthesis in the second line are useless too. By the way, it's normally good practice to put the function definitions before any code that actually "does something", so we will move both this and the next chunk of code *after* the function definitions.

```
with open(malicious_hash, 'rb')as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  print(lines)
```

This opens the file as *binary* but then calls `readlines()` - which returns a `list` of lines (separated by the line terminator), so something is wrong here. If we assume the file contains a hash we can simply use `read()`, and perhaps rename the variables just for readability: `malicious_hash_file` for the file name, and `malicious_hash` for the output of the `read()` call.

```
def cal_file_md5(filt_path):
    with open(filt_path, "rb") as f:
        file_hash = hashlib.md5()
        while chunk := f.read(1024 * 1024):
            file_hash.update(chunk)
    return file_hash.hexdigest()
```

This one is correct: it reads the file "filt_path" (was it "file_path" perhaps?) in 1 MB chunks, updates the hash after each read, and then returns the full hash.

```
def cal_folder_hash(folder):
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        print("Folder doesn't exist %s" % folder)
        return
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        path = os.path.join(folder, file)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            cal_folder_hash(path)
        else:
            print("File: %s" % path)
            md5 = cal_file_md5(path)
            print("MD5: %s\n" % md5)
```

This is the most interesting part: it checks that folder `folder` exists, then scans its contents. When it finds a subfolder (`os.path.isdir`) it calls itself recursively on the subfolder; when it finds a normal file it calls `cal_file_md5` on that file. All we need to add is to check if the hash returned by `cal_file_md5` is equal to the malicious hash we already have - if it is we will print a warning message together with the file name, if it is not we will proceed to the next iteration

```
cal_folder_hash("C:/Users/user/Downloads")
```

Ok, we finally call our main function.

So the revised code should be something like

```
import os
import hashlib

def cal_file_md5(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        file_hash = hashlib.md5()
        while chunk := f.read(1024 * 1024):
            file_hash.update(chunk)
    return file_hash.hexdigest()

def cal_folder_hash(folder):
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        print("Folder doesn't exist %s" % folder)
        return
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        path = os.path.join(folder, file)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            cal_folder_hash(path)
        else:
            md5 = cal_file_md5(path)
                if md5 == malicious_hash:
                    print("Malicious File found: %s" % path)

malicious_hash_file = "C:/Users/user/Downloads/malicious_hash.txt"
with open(malicious_hash_file, 'rb')as f:
  malicious_hash = f.read()
cal_folder_hash("C:/Users/user/Downloads")
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.

"malicious_hash.txt" is content all malicious md5 hash value string.
I want the hash value inside "malicious_hash.txt" compare to all file's hash value include recursive in path "C:/Users/user/Downloads" if it is match print "Match" and the path.